# List index out of bounds and stack overflow error

Tags: python, stack-overflow, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to get the max pair wise product using python this time around and the concepts of certain aspects are still new to me. I continue to get a list index out of bounds error and stackoverflows of which I do not know how to deal with given the fact that I can not choose types in Python.

I looked into enumerate and other iterate(ble) functions but to no avail. Id answered this could help future people with simple for loop questions in migration from C to python.

```
def max_pairwise_product(numbers):
    n = len(numbers)
    max_product = 0
    for first in range(n):
        for second in range(first + 1, n):
            max_product = max(max_product,
                numbers[first] * numbers[second])

    return max_product

def max_pairwise_product_fast(numbers):
    n = len(numbers)
    index1 = 1
    for i in range(2,n,1):
        if (numbers[i]>numbers[index1]):
            index1 = i
    if (index1 == 1):
        index2 = 2
    else:
        index2=1
    for i in range(1,n):
        if(numbers[i]!=numbers[index1] and numbers[i]>numbers[index2]):
            index2 = i
    return (numbers[index1]*numbers[index2])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_n = int(input())
    input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(max_pairwise_product_fast(input_numbers))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tevin/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(max_pairwise_product_fast(input_numbers))
  File "C:/Users/Tevin/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 27, in max_pairwise_product_fast
    return (numbers[index1]*numbers[index2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: First read into how to use for loops in python, you can iterate over lists directly and avoid indexes which is causing your problems and confusion, then read the following https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

why dont you find the 2 max numbers in your list and multiply them to get the max product. find the max of list then save it in some variable. remove it from the list and find the max again. then multiply this with your saved variable.

as for your code, what is this line for?

```
input_n = int(input())
```

you are not using the input_n variable anywhere.

and the line:

```
input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

your code will ask you for 2 inputs. when you first enter your input, it is saved in the input_n variable. then your second input is saved as input_numbers. something is wrong with the type of input you are giving the program.

Comment: Or the product of the 2 min numbers if they can be negative. (Also, I think this is exactly what OP is trying to do in the "fast" approach.)

Comment: I am pretty sure I am using input_n = int(input()) for the programs input because 1.) It was provided to my by the grader and 2.) when I delete it the program automatically goes into error. I mean I see your point though lol, idk why they do this.

Comment: The first line (reading a single number) is probably for the length of the list. Not needed for Python, but for other languages. There's nothing wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your `max_pairwise_product_fast` correctly, you are trying to find the largest and second largest number and multiply them. The problem is that you initialize `index1` as `1`, and `index2` with `1` or `2`, but array-indexes start with `0`. Thus, your code will fail for a list with only two elements, e.g. `[1,2]`. Change the starting indices to `0`, and change the `range` in the loops accordingly, and it will work.

You can also remove some of the checks, e.g. the `if/else`, as that's redundant with the check you have in your second loop. Also, by comparing `number[index1]` and `number[index2]` you could miss the highest product if the highest number appears twice, e.g. `[1,2,2]`.

Staying close to your original code, you can try this:

```
def max_pairwise_product_fast(numbers):
    n = len(numbers)
    index1 = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if numbers[i] > numbers[index1]:
            index1 = i
    index2 = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if index2 != index1 and numbers[i] > numbers[index2]:
            index2 = i
    return numbers[index1] * numbers[index2]
```

But you could also use `max` instead of those two loops:

```
def max_pairwise_product_fast(numbers):
    n = len(numbers)
    index1 = max(range(n), key=lambda i: numbers[i])
    index2 = max((i for i in range(n) if i != index1), key=lambda i: numbers[i])
    return numbers[index1] * numbers[index2]
```

Or sort the entire array and pick the highest two:

```
def max_pairwise_product_fast(numbers):
    second, first = sorted(numbers)[-2:]
    return first * second
```

Note, however, that this might still fail if the list includes negative numbers, e.g. `[1, 2, -3, -4]`. For this, you could call the same function again with all the numbers in the list negated and pick the higher of the two results.

Comment: I see - that is a very Pythonic way of approaching this. I think the course may have purposely given me irrational code so as to take me through the de-bugging, testing, troubleshooting and speed aspects of the issue - which I already did in C++ a while back but now wanted to do in Python. Everything you said made sense and has adjusted my way of thinking. I've been coding in C/C++ since the 8th grade and Python almost seems like cheating - but I like it.